# Simpler way to define convex functions

Tags: real-analysis, definition

I find the standard way of defining convex and concave functions slightly tricky. For me, it is the introduction of the new variable $0<λ<1$. However, I understand it intuitively. I was wondering if this definition is equivalent.

> Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a real function. We say $f$ is *convex* if for all $m,n \in [a,b]$ and for all $x \in (m,n)$ we have $$f(x) \leq \frac{x-m}{n-m}(f(n) - f(m)) + f(m) $$ If the inequality is reversed, we say $f$ is concave .

Comment: You can also define a convex function to be a function whose epigraph is convex. This explains why the same word "convex" is used for both sets and functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you require $n>m$ (which may be implicit in your reference to $x\in (m,n)$), then it looks like you've got equivalence between the standard definition and your new one, $\lambda=(x-m)/(n-m)$.  Caveat: I'm not sure your technique is any simpler.

Comment: Thanks! It's probably not simpler "objectively" but I guess it's helpful for me :P Of course, I will need to get a hang of the standard definition.